# Creating universal app. Does current user pay twice?

Tags: iphone, ipad, in-app-billing

I'm upgrading an iphone app to a universal iphone/ipad app.  A couple of questions...

1) If a user buys an iphone version (before both available) and then wants the ipad/universal version when released, does he pay again for the ipad version?
2) Are the inapp purchases the same between iphone and ipad....so, does he pay again?

Thanks

Fitto

Comment: So you have one binary for both?

Comment: For the app itself: definitely NO, as long as the app ID stays the same on iTunes Connect. Purchased apps can be used on up to 5 iOS devices, regardless of form factor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the user does not pay again. Think of it this way: it will behave the exact same as if you had an iPhone only app that a user installed on one iPhone and then installed on a new iPhone (or iPod). The fact that it is an iPad now is irrelevant. It's just a second device for the same app.

Comment: Thanks. That's a bit nasty in respect my app. I was hoping that users who already have the iphone version would see the advantage of the ipad version and purchase a new one. Also both versions now have many, many new features, particularly within the 'inApp' part of the program, which I was going to let the iphone users have with but really ought to be charging more for the ipad users.  If only Apple cold have an 'upgrade' charging route.  I wonder if I should release as a version two....hmmmmm.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your second question: Yes, in-app purchases are the same between iPhone and iPad. If you don't have a button that restores the user's in-app purchases anyway, the user could simply try to buy that in-app content again, then it will be downloaded and the user will not be charged for it anyway.